# jquery-ui autocomplete doesn't use original items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following:

```
class Department {
    constructor(data) {
        this.id = data && data.id || null
        this._name = data && data.name || null
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name
    }
    set name(v) {
        this._name = (v || "").trim() || null
    }
}

// In a different module:
import Department from "./Department"

async function searchDepartments(request, response) {
    let departments = []
    let result = await getDepartmentsFromServer(request.term)
    result.data.map((d) => {
        departments.push(new Department(d))
    })
    response(departments)
}

$("#myAutocomplete").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    delay: 500,
    source: searchDepartments,
    select: function (e, ui) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).val(ui.item.name) // ui.item.name is undefined; why?
    },
})
.each(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        let itemTemplate = "<div>" + item.name + "</div>"  // item.name is undefined; why?
        return $("<li>")
            .append(itemTemplate)
            .appendTo(ul)
    }
})
```

The problem is that, autocomplete internally uses different item objects; not the original ones supplied with response(departments). I found the following code in jquery autocomplete source:

```
// At line 2527
__response: function( content ) {
    if ( content ) {
        content = this._normalize( content );
    }
    ...
},

...

// At line 2566
_normalize: function( items ) {

    // assume all items have the right format when the first item is complete
    if ( items.length && items[ 0 ].label && items[ 0 ].value ) {
        return items;
    }
    return $.map( items, function( item ) {
        if ( typeof item === "string" ) {
            return {
                label: item,
                value: item
            };
        }
        return $.extend( {}, item, {
            label: item.label || item.value,
            value: item.value || item.label
        } );
    } );
},
```

Looks like, with $.extend, my department object's getter/setters are lost. Any suggestions to solve the issue?

PS: Of course, in this case, I can use item._name, but I need more generic approach.

Comment: Please provide an example of `departments` before it is sent to `response()`. The response array or objects should largely be string data. `$.extend()`: *Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.* It should just be adding the additional object to your existing object. I assume the object  is `{ id, _name, name() }`. Does this constructor work normally?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise trying to make the `Department` object first, then use the getter function before sending the results back to `response()`.

```
async function searchDepartments(request, response) {
    let departments = []
    let result = await getDepartmentsFromServer(request.term)
    $.each(result, function(k, d){
      var item = new Department(d);
      departments.push(item.name);
    });
    response(departments)
}
```

This would then send an array of String data to `response()` and it will be better handled.

Hope that helps.